# Drawer acts twice. What causes it?

Tags: android

I was trying to make an AlertDialog on no connection, but it was shown twice.

After two days of experimenting I've figured out that it's because my main_activity in the case block does everything twice. This code is from one of the tutorials I've found on the web (SimpleNotePad or smth). That's the main_activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false); //remove this line in the MainActivity.java

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    databaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();

    result = new DrawerBuilder()
            .withActivity(this)
            .withToolbar(mToolbar)
            .withActionBarDrawerToggle(true)
            .addDrawerItems(
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_home).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_home).withIdentifier(1),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_editor).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_edit).withIdentifier(2),
                    new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.title_settings).withIcon(FontAwesome.Icon.faw_list).withIdentifier(3)

            )
            .withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemClick(View view, int i, IDrawerItem drawerItem) {
                    if (drawerItem != null && drawerItem instanceof Nameable){
                        String name = ((Nameable)drawerItem).getName().getText(MainActivity.this);
                        mToolbar.setTitle(name);
                    }

                    if (drawerItem != null){
                        int selectedScren = drawerItem.getIdentifier();
                        switch (selectedScren){
                            case 1:
                                //go to List of Notes
                                openFragment(new NoteListFragment(), "Notes");
                                break;
                            case 2:
                                //go the editor screen
                                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, NoteEditorActivity.class));
                            case 3:
                                //go to settings screen, yet to be added
                                //this will be your home work
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Settings Clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }


            })
            .withOnDrawerListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDrawerOpened(View view) {
                    KeyboardUtil.hideKeyboard(MainActivity.this);

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onDrawerSlide(View view, float v) {

                }
            })
            .withFireOnInitialOnClick(true)
            .withSavedInstance(savedInstanceState)
            .build();
    if (savedInstanceState == null){
        result.setSelection(1);
    }


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private void openFragment(final Fragment fragment, String title){
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN)
            .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);
}
```

I have tried to limit fragments creation by doing this in case 1:

```
fragment =  (NoteListFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(String.valueOf(1));
                                if (fragment == null){
                                    fragment = new NoteListFragment();
                                    promptForDelete(fragment.toString());
                                    openFragment(fragment, "Notes");
                                }
                                //do nothing
                                break;
```

And after the case block adding this

```
if (fragment != null) {
                                FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
                                fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment, String.valueOf(1)).commitAllowingStateLoss();
                            }
```

But with no success. What is forcing main_activity to create everything twice? And how can I change that?

Comment: You forgot to write `break` after the second `case` statement?

Comment: No ... case 3 does nothing more than showing Toast ... it is mistake but not causing this problem

Comment: @Javanshir It's the part from the tutorial project, which contains the same mistake I'm trying to deal with my project. Mine is different in minor details (like case statments) and doesn't have the the mistake.

Comment: Then you probably have bad tutorials ) if you want to create a navigation drawer, I would suggest you to follow this tutorial:
https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer
You are trying to add everything in one statement (items, clickListeners, drawerListeners etc.), that is not good )